# Trend micro detects an "Unauthorized file Encryption" in Install4J-generated installer

Tags: install4j, antivirus

I'm generating an installer for my open source project with Install4J and a user reported that its company-controlled TrendMicro antivirus blocks the installer due to "Unauthorized file Encryption".
I don't find anything related to this issue on the web.

Did anyone ever encounter this issue ?

The issue was reported here: https://github.com/Ginj-capture/Ginj/issues/14

Vicne

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Users with this anti-virus software will have to add the installer to the exclusion list for behavior monitoring.

Apart from that, in these cases reporting false positives to the vendor of the anti-virus software is the best option.

Comment: Thanks. I was surprised that it was not flagged as containing suspect **code**, but as unauthorized file **encryption**. Do some parts of Install4J use encryption (and not just compression) ?

Comment: No, there is no encryption in the install4j runtime. This is a false positive.